# javascript dosen't read the value in html

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, innerhtml

So i want to make a program that start countingdown from a value that you choose but the issue is when i try to bring the value to javascript it dosen't work but when i type the value in html it work

here is my html code

```
<body>
<div id="count">
    <input id="time" type="number" min="0">
    <button id="button">Press here to begin the countdown</button>
</div>
<script src="lol.js"></script>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
var count = document.getElementById("count"),
    seconds = document.getElementById("time").value ,
    btn = document.getElementById("button"),
    secondPass;
    countDown = setInterval(function() {
        secondPass()
    } , 1000);
btn.onclick =         
function secondPass(){
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),
        remseconds = seconds % 60;
    count.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remseconds;
    if (remseconds < 10){
        remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
    }
    if (seconds> 0 ){
        seconds = seconds - 1;
    }   
    else {
        clearInterval(countDown)
        count.innerHTML = "done !"
    }
}
```

Comment: please post ur input and desired output

Comment: FYI: setTimeout is not accurate, this will not be a great countdown timer since it drfits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code was that you were trying to get the `value` before it was entered.
If I understood correctly, you wanted this:

```js
var count = document.getElementById("count"),
    btn = document.getElementById("button"),
    secondPass;


btn.addEventListener("click", secondPass);

function secondPass() {
    var seconds = document.getElementById("time").value

    var countDown = setInterval(function () {
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),
            remseconds = seconds % 60;
        count.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remseconds;
        if (remseconds < 10) {
            remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
        }
        if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds = seconds - 1;
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(countDown)
            count.innerHTML = "done !"
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="count">
    <input id="time" type="number" min="0">
    <button id="button">Press here to begin the countdown</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted ! Thanks a lot my brother

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful :) You can mark this answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Main mistake - on time when you declare `seconds` variable - time input is empty.
I fixed your example, so you can figure out what was wrong

```
var count = document.getElementById("count"),
    seconds,
    btn = document.getElementById("button"),
    countDown
  
  btn.onclick = function() {
    seconds =  document.getElementById("time").value;
    countDown = setInterval(function() {
      secondPass()
    }, 1000);
  }
    
function secondPass(){
     console.log('S', seconds)
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),
        remseconds = seconds % 60;
    count.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remseconds;
    if (remseconds < 10){
        remseconds = "0" + remseconds;
    }
    if (seconds> 0 ){
        seconds = seconds - 1;
    }   
    else {
        clearInterval(countDown)
        count.innerHTML = "done !"
    }
}
```